# Error While Loading Property file in Spark-submit

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I am new to Scala/Spark.I am facing the below problem. Please suggest me something.

**I have Property file contains (prop.conf):**

```
spark.shuffle.memoryFraction    0.5
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead      712
spark.default.parallelism       100
spark.network.timeout   1500000
```

**And I am executing it like this :**

```
spark-submit --class org.sia.chapter03App.AppTest  --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 40 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 3100m --files /home/biadmin/ddls/20160608/hive-site.xml  --properties-file /home/prop.conf  --jars  /usr/iop/4.1.0.0/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar /home/original-chapter03App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have written it like this:

**--properties-file /home/prop.conf**

But execution gets failed and Error is:

> User class threw exception:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if you exclude the `--properties-file` argument it works?

Comment: Yes if i mention all configuration manually (--conf) in spark-submit then it works properly.

Comment: Please include a code snippet of what you did exactly? along with the version of Spark you are using.